# Why do I get the "number stored as text" error on a few values?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I would like to create some rows in a spreadsheet using Apache Poi. To do so I have to format the number to meet some specifications

So my initial number is a double (in a String ><) like this one

```
String initial = "1234.56";
```

and I would like to store it in this format

```
String wanted = "1 234";
```

So I use this code to parse it (and it works fine)

```
wanted = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.FRANCE).format(Double.valueOf(initial).intValue())
```

But when I create the spreadsheet, and open it (with excel), I get this error **ONLY** a few values

> number stored as text

I tried to solve it using

```
cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
```

but it did not work.

The strange thing is that this error is not on all the values (all values come from the same function). See this screenshot for example

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Did I do something wrong ? Did I miss something ? Does someone have an idea to solve it ?

Comment: Thanks, your comment helped to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved using

```
HSSFCellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
style.setDataFormat(HSSFDataFormat.getBuiltinFormat("#,##0"));
```

and

```
int value = Double.valueOf(initial).intValue();
cell.setCellValue(value);
```

I already tried using this DataFormat, but in order to work, you need to insert a number, not a String.

```
cell.setCellValue("12345");  //Will be inserted as 12345. Echec !
cell.setCellValue(Integer.valueOf("12345"));  //Will be inserted as 12 345. Success ;)
```

Comment: Can't get this working with XSSFDataFormat library for newer Excels.